# Grunt combine SCSS and CSS files

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

In my application SCSS files gets compiled to CSS files and all the files included in one main.css file. There are some other CSS files which also gets included in main.css file, how can I using Grunt create one CSS file from all these CSS and SCSS files?

Note: All my CSS file is in client folder and SCSS file after compilation goes to public folder.

MSK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is (file)-*concatination*.

There is an excellent plugin for grunt: **[grunt-contrib-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat)**

Example-Configuration (static):

```
concat: {
    dist: {
        //Add your files to src
        src: [
          'client-folder/file1.css',
          'public/compiled.css'
           ],
      dest: 'output/style.css',
    },
},
```

Example-Configuration (dynamic):

```
concat: {
    dist: {
        src: [
          //Will use all .css files in client-folder/
          'client-folder/**.css',
          'public/compiled.css'
           ],
      dest: 'output/style.css',
    },
},
```

`grunt concat:dist` will then concat the content of your `src` files into the `dest` file.

You can dig deeper into the documentation for more grunting fun.

Comment: Thanks @SpazzMarticus,
One thing if I use this task in watch it goes into infinite loop any idea about this?

Comment: @MSK If you watch the files you generate it will loop infinitely, because those files of course change. You need to exclude the files like '!output/style.css'

Comment: I am not watching output/style.css
This is my task
`code
    sass: {
      build: {
        options: {
          sourcemap: 'none',
          style: 'compress'
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: globalConfig.source + '/css/',
          src: ['*.scss'],
          dest: globalConfig.target + '/css/',
          ext: '.css',
        }]
      }
    }
`

Comment: @MSK Can you post your full Gruntfile.js and the console-output somewhere?

Comment: @ SpazzMarticus here you go
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0316ebb3ce5fdde4626d

Comment: @MSK Does it help if you set `spawn: true`? If not, please open a new question. I can't find the error :(

Comment: @ SpazzMarticus looks like spawn: true is working :)